# How to create an andoid Vecor Asset from any image I have?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have some icons as png that I want to create a vector asset for.
Let's say I want to create a heart; I found this code on StackOverflow:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF414BB2"
        android:pathData="M12,21.35l-1.45,-1.32C5.4,15.36 2,12.28 2,8.5 2,5.42 4.42,3 7.5,3c1.74,0 3.41,0.81 4.5,2.09C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3 19.58,3 22,5.42 22,8.5c0,3.78 -3.4,6.86 -8.55,11.54L12,21.35z"/>
</vector>
```

The thing is, I have many other icons I want, like all the sports ( tennis, football, etc).
How can I do that? is there a website or a software for that?

Comment: "I have some icons as png that I want to create a vector asset for" -- you will find that to be impractical. Ask your graphic designer to give you SVG artwork for the icons, then use Android Studio's Vector Asset wizard to attempt to create a vector drawable from the SVG. Even that may not work, as some SVGs use options that the vector drawable format does not support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use online image convertor to convert format, there are many website available that can convert png image to vector asset,

You can try this site,

[convert.io](https://convertio.co/png-svg/)

But I would suggest rather than converting png to vector asset, try finding new vector asset cause sometimes it causes data lose in conversion and that result in image being blurry or losing its elements.